# Streaming response not seems to be workig with form-data

Tags: node.js, react-native, axios, openai-api

I am working on a React Native application that involves receiving streaming responses from two different APIs (chatapi and visionApi) using Server-Sent Events (SSE). The streaming response from chatapi works perfectly, updating my UI in real-time as expected — I can see each word appearing one by one. However, I'm facing issues with the visionApi, where the UI only updates after the entire response is received, instead of updating in real-time as the stream progresses. I also tried to log the response in visionApi the logs says it is coming in events same as chatApi.

Both APIs send their responses in chunks, and I handle these chunks using a handleStreamResponse function that updates my component's state to include the new data. Despite the similar setup for both APIs, only the chatapi's streaming updates behave as expected.

Here is a simplified version of my handleStreamResponse function:

```
const handleStreamResponse = useCallback((textChunk) => {
  setChatData((prevChatData) => {
    let newChatData = [...prevChatData];
    let lastSystemMessageIndex = newChatData.length - 1;
    newChatData[lastSystemMessageIndex] = {
      ...newChatData[lastSystemMessageIndex],
      content: newChatData[lastSystemMessageIndex].content + textChunk,
    };
    return newChatData;
  });
  scrollViewRef?.current.scrollToEnd({ animated: true });
}, []);
```

And here's how I call the APIs:

```
  const handleSend = async (question) => {
    try {
      if (!canRequest) {
        Keyboard.dismiss();
        setShouldShowCreditMessage(true);
      } else {
        if (question != "") {
          setIsLoading(true);
          mychat.push(question);
          SetEnterText("");
          // add user input and placeholder for response to the chat data
          let tempArr = Array.from(chatData);
          tempArr.push({
            role: "user",
            content: question,
            attachment: attachment ? attachment : false,
          });
          tempArr.push({ role: "system", content: "" });
          setChatData(tempArr);

          // This code snippet checks for the presence of an attachment and calls different APIs based on the condition, handling responses accordingly.
          if (attachment) {
            await visionApi(
              question,
              attachment,
              device.deviceId,
              (data) => {
                Keyboard.dismiss();
                handleStreamResponse(data);
              },
              (data) => onSuccess(data)
            );
          } else {
            await chatapi(
              question,
              device.deviceId,
              (data) => {
                Keyboard.dismiss();
                handleStreamResponse(data);
              },
              (data) => onSuccess(data)
            );
          }
        }
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("handleSend error ==>>", error);
    }
  };
```

And here's how I display the messages in UI:

```
          <FlatList
            ref={scrollViewRef}
            scrollEnabled={true}
            data={chatData}
            keyExtractor={(item) => chatData.indexOf(item)}
            contentContainerStyle={{
              // position: "relative",
              // zIndex: 9999,
              paddingTop: shouldShowExamples ? 50 : 0,
              paddingBottom: 30,
              backgroundColor: colors.darkblack,
            }}
            onContentSizeChange={() =>
              scrollViewRef?.current.scrollToEnd({ animated: true })
            }
            keyboardDismissMode="on-drag"
            renderItem={(item, index) =>
              item.item.role === "user" ? (
                <>
                  {selectedMessageIndex.index == item.index &&
                    renderMessageTooltip(item.item.content, item.item.role)}
                  <Pressable
                    onPress={() => handlePress(item)}
                    style={{
                      ...styles.bluechatcontainer,
                      backgroundColor: selectedMessageIndex?.isClickedOutSide
                        ? colors.dimBlack
                        : selectedMessageIndex?.index == item.index
                        ? colors.pureWhite
                        : colors.dimBlackOpacity,
                      position: "relative",
                      width: "100%",
                      overflow: "hidden",
                    }}
                    key={index}
                  >
                    <Image
                      source={icons.user}
                      style={{ width: 30, height: 30 }}
                    />
                    <View>
                      <Text style={styles.messageTitle}>You</Text>
                      {item.item.attachment &&
                        renderAttachment({
                          isResponse: true,
                          data: item.item.attachment,
                        })}
                      <Text
                        key={index}
                        style={{
                          ...styles.rightChattext,
                          marginStart: 20,
                          color: selectedMessageIndex?.isClickedOutSide
                            ? colors.white
                            : selectedMessageIndex?.index == item.index
                            ? colors.white
                            : colors.dimWhite,
                        }}
                      >
                        {item.item.content}
                      </Text>
                    </View>
                  </Pressable>
                </>
              ) : (
                <>
                  <Pressable
                    onPress={() => handlePress(item)}
                    style={{
                      ...styles.greychatcontainer,
                      backgroundColor: selectedMessageIndex?.isClickedOutSide
                        ? colors.apiBG
                        : selectedMessageIndex?.index == item.index
                        ? colors.lightBlack
                        : colors.dimLightBlack,
                      position: "relative",
                      width: "100%",
                    }}
                    key={index}
                  >
                    <Image
                      source={icons.blueLogo}
                      style={{ width: 30, height: 30, borderRadius: 15 }}
                    />
                    <View style={styles.respCont}>
                      <Text style={styles.messageTitle}>JustThink</Text>
                      <View
                        style={{
                          marginStart: 20,
                        }}
                      >
                        <Markdown
                          key={index}
                          style={{
                            text: {
                              fontFamily: fonts.regular,
                              color: selectedMessageIndex?.isClickedOutSide
                                ? colors.white
                                : selectedMessageIndex.index == item.index
                                ? colors.white
                                : colors.dimWhite,
                              maxWidth: "85%",
                            },
                            bullet_list_icon: {
                              fontFamily: fonts.semiBold,
                              color: selectedMessageIndex?.isClickedOutSide
                                ? colors.white
                                : selectedMessageIndex.index == item.index
                                ? colors.white
                                : colors.dimWhite,
                            },
                            ordered_list_icon: {
                              fontFamily: fonts.semiBold,
                              color: selectedMessageIndex?.isClickedOutSide
                                ? colors.white
                                : selectedMessageIndex.index == item.index
                                ? colors.white
                                : colors.dimWhite,
                              maxWidth: "85%",
                            },
                          }}
                        >
                          {item.item.content}
                        </Markdown>
                      </View>
                    </View>
                  </Pressable>
                  {selectedMessageIndex.index == item.index &&
                    renderMessageTooltip(item.item.content, item.item.role)}
                </>
              )
            }
          />
```

And here's how api calling is setup:

```
export const chatapi = async (question, deviceId, callback, onSuccess) => {
  try {
    let data = JSON.stringify({
      user: question,
    });

    let es = new EventSource(`${BASE_URL}/v1/add_chat`, {
      method: "post",
      headers: {
        deviceid: deviceId,
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: data,
    });

    es.addEventListener("open", (event) => {
      console.log("open ===>>>", event.type);
    });

    es.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
      // console.log("message event  ==>>", event.data);
      if (!event) {
        console.log("!event");
        es.close();
      } else {
        const data = JSON.parse(event.data);
        // console.log("New message event data:", data);
        // console.log('event.data?.event === "close" ==>>', data?.event);
        if (data?.event === "close") {
          es.close();
        } else if (data?.user) {
          onSuccess(data?.user);
        } else {
          callback(data);
        }
      }
    });

    es.addEventListener("error", (event) => {
      if (event.type === "error") {
        console.error("Connection error:", event.message);
        es.close();
      } else if (event.type === "exception") {
        console.error("Error:", event.message, event.error);
        es.close();
      }
    });

    es.addEventListener("close", (event) => {
      console.log("Close SSE connection.", event);
      setTimeout(() => {
        es.close();
        es.removeAllEventListeners();
      }, 1000);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("chatapi error ==>>", error);
  }
};

export const visionApi = async (
  question,
  attachment,
  deviceId,
  callback,
  onSuccess
) => {
  try {
    const ATTACHMENT_TYPES = {
      img: "image",
      pdf: "pdf",
    };
    console.log("vision api attachment ==<>>>>", attachment);
    let fileUri = Platform.select({
      ios: attachment.uri.replace("file://", ""),
      android: attachment.uri,
    });

    let data = new FormData();
    data.append("file", {
      name: attachment.type.includes(ATTACHMENT_TYPES.pdf)
        ? attachment.name
        : attachment.fileName,
      type: attachment.type,
      uri: fileUri,
    });
    data.append("prompt", question);

    let es = new EventSource(`${BASE_URL}/v1/image_editing`, {
      method: "post",
      maxBodyLength: Infinity,
      headers: {
        deviceid: deviceId,
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
        "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
        Connection: "keep-alive",
      },
      body: data,
    });

    es.addEventListener("open", (event) => {
      console.log("open ===>>>", event.type);
    });

    es.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
      if (!event) {
        console.log("!event");
        es.close();
      } else {
        const data = JSON.parse(event.data);
        // console.log("New message event data:", data);
        // console.log('event.data?.event === "close" ==>>', data?.event);
        if (data?.event === "close") {
          es.close();
        } else if (data?.user) {
          onSuccess(data?.user);
        } else {
          // console.log("message event  ==>>", event.data);
          callback(data);
        }
      }
    });

    es.addEventListener("error", (event) => {
      if (event.type === "error") {
        console.error("Connection error:", event.message);
        es.close();
      } else if (event.type === "exception") {
        console.error("Error:", event.message, event.error);
        es.close();
      }
    });

    es.addEventListener("close", (event) => {
      console.log("Close SSE connection.", event);
      setTimeout(() => {
        es.close();
        es.removeAllEventListeners();
      }, 1000);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("vision error ==>>", error);
  }
};
```

What I've tried:

1. I've ensured that both APIs are set up similarly and that the server is sending the data in chunks for both.
2. I've tried forcing re-renders after each chunk is received to ensure that the UI updates (which made no difference for the visionApi).
3. I checked to make sure that the handleStreamResponse function is being called with each chunk received from the visionApi.

Despite these efforts, the UI still only updates after the entire message from the visionApi has been received.

**My question:**
What could be causing the streaming updates from the visionApi to not update the UI in real-time, unlike the chatapi? Are there any specific considerations or common pitfalls in handling SSE with React Native that I might be missing?

Any insights or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated!